# How to integrate a copy button to a form that is created using cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

There are FundApplication and ExpenseRequest, FundApplication has_many expense_requests.

[image]

Pressing the 'Add Expense' Button will add expense requests and is working fine. Now my client asks me to implement a copy button here

[image]

What he wants is to add a button that inserts a new expense request but copy's the expense request's data the button belongs into the fields of newly created expense_request

I tried
[How to create a copy of item added in cocoon nsted form rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198658/how-to-create-a-copy-of-item-added-in-cocoon-nsted-form-rails)
[How could I clone a child object in Rails using cocoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577571/how-could-i-clone-a-child-object-in-rails-using-cocoon)

None of them worked for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to `cocoon`-specific callbacks; in particular, `cocoon:after-insert`. You can do something like this (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formContainer").on(
    "cocoon:after-insert", (event, insertedItem, originalEvent) {
      console.log("event: ", event)
      console.log("insertedItem: ", insertedItem)
      console.log("originalEvent: ", originalEvent)
  })
})
```

Using the original event (the `click` event) you can find the fields belonging to that button and get the values from that, and use those values to set the values in the newly inserted item.